# search for text in recently created files

Tags: unix, grep, find

I'm working on a very old Unix system and I need to search for text in files created within the last 3 hours. Here's my current command:

```
grep Qual file.txt
```

I want to only search for Qual in files created in the last 3 hours...help

Answer (score 1):

This can be a way:

```
find /your/path -mmin  -180 -type f -exec grep "Qual" +
                ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                3 hours     files         look for Qual in files found
```

Comment: `-mtime -3` is within the last 3 *days*, not *hours*... For 3 hours, you would want `-mmin 180`, assuming GNU `find`. Some older variants of `find` may not support sub-day granularity.

Comment: Could also replace `{} \;` with `+`, so it doesn't waste a new subshell on every `grep`